# Solutions to the differential equation $x(x+1)yy' = xy + 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving the equation

$x(x+1)yy' - xy - 1 = 0$

---

### I will list the steps I followed:

(I'm sure I have made some huge mistake.)

---

1. Divide by $x(x+1)$

$yy' - y/(x+1) - 1/x(x+1) = 0$

---

2. Integrate w.r.t dx.

$∫(yy')dx - ∫(y/(x+1))dx - ∫(1/x(x+1))dx = 0$

---

3. Integrating by parts $∫f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - ∫f'(x)g(x)dx$

$f(x) = y$
$g(x) = y$

$∫yy'dx = y.y - ∫y'.y.dx$
$∫yy'dx = y²/2$

---

4. Integrating by parts

$f(x) = y$
$g(x) = \ln(x+1)$

$∫(y/(x+1))dx = y.\ln(x+1) - ∫(dy/dx).\ln(x+1).dx$
$∫(y/(x+1))dx = y.\ln(x+1) - ∫\ln(x+1).dy$
$∫(y/(x+1))dx = y.\ln(x+1) - y.\ln(x+1)$
$∫(y/(x+1))dx = 0$

---

5. Integrating last term

$∫(dx/x(x+1)) = ∫(dx/x) - ∫dx/(x+1)$
$∫(dx/x(x+1)) = \ln(x) - \ln(x+1)$
$∫(dx/x(x+1)) = \ln(x/(x+1))$

---

$y = √2(\ln(x/x+1))$
$\ln(x/x+1) < 1$ when $0<x<∞$

$y$ becomes imaginary. Judging by that I am sure I have made some huge mistakes, could anyone help me with this.

Comment: 1) Use \ln to get a nicer $\ln$! 2) Your equation is not linear. 3) You can check for yourself if you have the right function, just plug it in your original differential equation!

Comment: @NigelOvermars I am not sure if I understand your third point.

Comment: Of course it's wrong to say $\int\ln(x+1)\,dy=y\ln(x+1)$

Comment: dy/dx is not a fraction; you can't just cancel dx as if it were a number

Comment: The ODE itself belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Comment: You say that your differential equation is linear, but it is not. Are you sure you wrote it correctly? Where did you find this differential equation?

Comment: @mickep I had erroneously put the term linear, I have removed it now. I arrived at this equation while solving for a problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$x(x+1)yy' - xy - 1 = 0$$
Let $y(x)=\frac{1}{z(x)} \quad\to\quad x(x+1)\frac{1}{z} \frac{z'}{z^2} -x\frac{1}{z} -1=0$
$$z'=\frac{1}{x(x+1)} z^3 +\frac{1}{x+1}z^2 $$
This is an Abel's ODE of the first kind. In the present case, as far as I know there is no standard special function available to express the solution on a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution $z=x y$, $y'= \dfrac{xz'-z}{x^2}$, gives us
$$(x+1)z\dfrac{xz'-z}{x^2} - z=1$$
or
$$-(x+1)z^2 + x(x+1)zz'- x^2z=x^2$$
Which implies
$$z'=-\dfrac{z}{x}+\dfrac{x}{x+1}+\dfrac{x}{x+1}\dfrac{1}{z}$$
Which is a [Chini](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToODEs.html#539501524) equation, which tend to be horrible to solve by hand. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D-y%5E2%2Fx+%2B+xy%2F(x%2B1)+%2B+x%2F(x%2B1)) also doesn't give a closed form solution.

Maybe someone else sees how to continue, so consider this answer incomplete.

Comment: Please note that the name is [*Riccati*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacopo_Riccati). In Italian, the word *ricatti* is the plural of *ricatto*, that is, *blackmail*.

Comment: @egreg That's the second time today that I wrote his name wrong. Edited and made a mental note. Hopefully it wil stick.

Comment: @egreg Are you sure? ^^

Comment: Maybe knowing the meaning of the wrong spelling, you'll be luckier. `;-)`

Comment: @Nigel Overmars :  There is a mistake in $$z'=-\dfrac{z^2}{x}+\dfrac{xz}{x+1}+\dfrac{x}{x+1}$$ The correct equation is $$z'=-\dfrac{z}{x}+\dfrac{x}{x+1}+\dfrac{x}{(x+1)z}$$ which isn't a Riccati ODE.

Comment: @JJacquelin You are completely right. Mathematica says it is a Chini equation, which is a generalisation of the Riccati/Abel equation. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$x(x+1)yy'-xy-1=0$

$x(x+1)y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=xy+1$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x+1}+\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $x=e^t-1$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{e^t}=e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore e^{-t}y\dfrac{dy}{dt}=e^{-t}y+\dfrac{1}{(e^t-1)e^t}$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-y=\dfrac{1}{e^t-1}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf